# Help on the following indefinite integral: $\int\big(\sqrt{1-t^2}\big)^{n-1}\mathrm{d}t$

Tags: integration, indefinite-integrals

I would like to evaluate the following indefinite integral
$$
\int\big(\sqrt{1-t^2}\big)^{n-1}\mathrm{d}t,
$$
but -alas- I am not familiarized enough with this kind of integration. I have been suggested to use the substitution $t=\sin\varphi$, but I have some difficulties in applying that. Could you please help me? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Could you be more specific about your difficulties?

Comment: Note too that if $n$ is odd the integrand is just a polynomial.

Comment: Both Maple and Mathematica answer $$t{\mbox{$_2$F$_1$}(1/2,1/2-n/2;\,3/2;\,{t}^{2})} $$ even under additional assumptions on $n$.

Comment: @user64494, and what does $F_1$ stand for?

Comment: @Travis, thanks, I'm looking at this again, I'll come back soon. What about the above comment of user64494?

Comment: @nullgeppetto :This is the standard notation of [the hypergeometric function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_function).

Comment: Thanks @user64494, so does this have a close form? To be honest, I was expecting the above integral to be in close-form.

Comment: @nullgeppetto: Yes, this is a closed form expression.

Comment: Thank you very much @user64494. I will try and I will return. Meanwhile, if you like to post your approach, be my guest! Thanks again!

Comment: @Travis could you be more specific for the case where n is odd? You said that the integral should be just a polynomial. Thanks!

Comment: @nullgeppetto: If $n$ is odd, say, $n = 2m + 1$, then the integrand is $(\sqrt{1  - t^2})^{n - 1} = (1 - t^2)^m$, which is a polynomial. We can expand it as a sum of monomials, namely as $\sum_{k = 0}^m {m \choose k} (-1)^{m - k} t^{2k}$, and integrate term-by-term.

Comment: (Well, strictly speaking the integrand is the restriction of that polynomial to $[-1, 1]$, but this doesn't affect integration on that interval.)

Answer (score 4):

By replacing $t$ with $\sin \phi$ we are left with:
$$ I= \int \cos^n\phi\,d\phi \tag{1}$$
and this integral can be approached by considering the Fourier cosine series of the integrand function:
$$\cos^n\phi = \frac{1}{2^n}\left(e^{i\phi}+e^{-i\phi}\right)^n = \frac{1}{2^n}\sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor n/2\rfloor}\binom{n}{k}2\cos((n-2k)\phi).\tag{2}$$
The RHS of $(2)$ is quite easy to integrate.

Comment: @nullgeppetto: See also [Wallis' integrals](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wallis'_integrals).

Comment: Hi @Lucian, thanks for your comment! If I'm not mistaken, Wallis integrals are definite, and I cannot find some way to generalize them. Have you something in mind?

Comment: Dear Jack, now I can understand your approach. However, I am wondering whether there is something "less complex" than this. I mean that the summation in the Fourier series makes it rather inconvenient for my purposes. Is there any way to express the integral in terms of the Gamma function? Thank you very much!

Comment: @nullgeppetto: if the integral is considered over $[0,1]$, just replace $t$ with $\sqrt{x}$ to get an integral that depends on the Beta function ($B(a,b)=\frac{\Gamma(a)\,\Gamma(b)}{\Gamma(a+b)}$). Otherwise, the integral is given by an incomplete Beta function.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio: I could try to make $t\in[0,1]$, but do you mean that the integral has to get as limits $0$ and $1$ exactly, or is it possible to have the limits starting from $0$ to $k\leq1$. Thanks!

Comment: @nullgeppetto: in such a case, after replacing $t$ with $\sqrt{x}$, have a look at http://mathworld.wolfram.com/IncompleteBetaFunction.html

Comment: Thank you very much @JackD'Aurizio, I'll do as you suggest. I will return after that, so apologies in advance for bothering you again!